# Vectorized string concatenation in Ruby like R's paste function

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays in Ruby that I'd like to element-wise concatenate together. In R this is as simple as using the `paste` function because it is vectorized:

```
# R
values <- c(1, 2, 3)
names <- c("one", "two", "three")
paste(values, names, sep = " as ")
[1] "1 as one"   "2 as two"   "3 as three"
```

In Ruby it's a bit more complicated and I'd like to know if there's a more direct way:

```rb
# Ruby
values = [1, 2, 3]
names = ["one", "two", "three"]
values.zip(names).map { |zipped| zipped.join(" as ") }
 => ["1 as one", "2 as two", "3 as three"]
```

Comment: The way you used is a common way of handling it in Ruby. There are alternate ways, but none are really a big improvement, just a different path to the same result.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way:

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
names = ["one", "two", "three"].to_enum 
values.map{|v|"#{v} as #{names.next}"}
# => ["1 as one", "2 as two", "3 as three"]
```

This however gets elaborate with more then 2 arrays. OP's version works better with multiple arrays.

Comment: Good point about more than two arrays. I didn't know `zip` could handle multiple arguments. Thanks!